# Uninstallation of application leaves leftovers such as BLA's and CU's

Tags: deployment, websphere, jmx

I came across problem of cyclic (deploy-undeploy) deployments to WebSphere 7, where uninstalled application leaves dirty workplace. IBM has a fix ([PM20642](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM20642))for it in cumulative updates starting from 7.0.15, but I see no difference. Orphaned folder for business level app and composition unit are still present after undeployment.I'm using JMX admin client for connectivity to the server.

Anyone has any experience in dealing with this issue?

Comment: Worth to mention removal of orphaned folder is not an option due to connectivity to the remote system over JMX.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IBM's fix and it still fails, I would say open a PMR with IBM to help you investigate. It could be their fix didn't work as they expected or maybe the fix pack was not applied correctly. In either scenario way I would say you may want IBM's support to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks, always an option to get in touch with the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have remote access via JMX, then you could try to use `$AdminConfig deleteDocument` in wsadmin to remove the files/folders from the configuration repository.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I'm looking for more clean solution.